# talkd doesn't print a message

Tags: terminal, users, chat

I wanted to use talk with my brother (we both have Debian Jessie). So I installed `inetutils-inetd`, `inetutils-talk`, and `inetutils-talkd`. Now I wanted to try whether it works. So I created a testuser named foo. Then I logged in as this user and as my original user. I switched `mesg` on both terminals to yes and then tried this on my originals user:

```
$talk foo
[Service connection established.]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
```

And foo never gets a message like it is described in the manpage. I also checked that `inetd` is running and enabled `talkd` by `inetd`. Here's the only line in `/etc/inetd.conf` that isn't uncommented.:

```
talk    stream  tcp nowait  root    /usr/sbin/talkd talkd
```

I also tried to let both users try to talk to each other, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how I can get talk to work?

Comment: I remember that the package was called "ntalk", not "talk". Only the client command was "talk".

Comment: As i know the server command is talkd and is contained in inetutils-talk. I checked that it is at /usr/sbin/talkd. The description of the package inetutils-talk also says that it contains the server.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici there are (were?) multiple talk implementations; ntalk is/was one of them. There is/was also ytalk.

Comment: Also this SF Q&A might be what you're looking for: http://serverfault.com/questions/166858/help-configuring-talk-talkd/166907#166907

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a *long* time since I ran `talkd` (or actually `ytalk`, if I remember correctly). There is one thing I see that seems wrong—talk is a *UDP* protocol.

So your `inetd.conf` line is wrong. It took a bit to dig up the right line, but according to [The Debian Administrator's Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.inetd.html), it is:

```
talk   dgram  udp wait    nobody.tty /usr/sbin/in.talkd in.talkd
```

If you have a firewall running, you'll have to let through the traffic as well. For example:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport talk -j ACCEPT
```

`talk` is port 517 if your firewall config program won't take the name.

Comment: I changed the line to yours, except that the last two fields still point to talkd not to in.talkd. That's because i don't have in.talkd and it's contained in the talkd-package which would uninstall the GNU versions of talk but i think it should work with the GNU version. I don't have a firewall running.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu its possible its using the ntalk port, try that one as well. (And I assume you reloaded inetd after changing from TCP to UDP?)

Comment: Sorry, now i can't follow anymore. What do you mean with ntalk port? Where do i specify it?

Comment: Ah now i got it what ntalk is. That leads me to the next problem. The open-bsd version (talkd) contains in.ntalkd and in.talkd but the GNU version (inetutils-talkd) only contains talkd so ntalkd is missing.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu Sorry, was AFK for a bit. You specify the port in /etc/inetd.conf (and then must reload inetd after each change). But it sounds like you got a different `talk` program to work... so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: The open-bsd version of talkd has a second binary called in.ntalkd. The GNU version doesn't have this, i think this is the source of the problem. Thanks for the remembrance, but i did restart after each change.

Answer (score 1):

I now just switched to talk from open-bsd. I will continue trying to get the GNU version running and will edit this question when i did it. Thanks for all the help.